# Is it possible to reset a JUnit test?

Tags: java, junit

At the beginning of my test I have an Array List with items in it, during my test I add more items and then in a different test I clear the array. Now in my third test I would like to access the array as it was during the @Before stage - before any of the tests were ran.

Is it at all possible to do this or would I have to do a separate test file for this?

Comment: Why not just call the method that's annotated with @Before in the beginning of your test?

Comment: `@Before` is run before every single unit test. Each test is run in isolation. I believe there is a way to have a function called once before any tests are run however via the `@BeforeClass` annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember an important Junit Testing principle: **EVERY UNIT TEST IS INDEPENDENT FROM ANOTHER.**. This means that it should not matter which tests you run in different order, they shall always pass.

So what to do here?

If you have a @Before method that fills an Array List, then declare this Array List outside the method like this:

```
private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

@Before
public void myMethod(){
// do something, fill your list, etc.
}
```

So, if you are in the need of modifying this array list in your test, then you should have a copy of this array list in everyone of them. Remember as I said before, tests should pass no matter what the order they are executed, so you should not suppose that one test is going to remove stuff so the other can start. What it is only for sure is that the @Before method will run before everything else.

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
List<String> myCopyList = new ArrayList<String>(myList);
//work with your copy
}
```

This will guarantee that you will not modify the list outside the method!, and every test will start with the same data.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably that you populate the list in the `@Before` but don't create a new instance.

** Wrong way **

```
 private List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();

 @Before
 public void setup(){
    // add stuff to list
 }
```

In the above, all tests are using the same instance of the list so modifications will be seen by other tests.

** Right way **

```
 private List<String> value;

 @Before
 public void setup(){
    value = new ArrayList<String>();
    // add stuff to list
    // or you could clean the list then populate
 }
```

The the above method, there is a new list for each test so there is no possible interaction between tests.